# Can you explain the grammar of this sentence please: "movies to have a good cry to"

Tags: grammar

I try to understand using of 'to' at the end of this sentence. I understand the meaning but grammar is confusing me. Can someone explain it to me please? I hope I could express myself. I googled but couldn't find anyting. 'songs to dance ***to***', 'songs to make up ***to***' etc, have same construction. Is it about the verbs '***dance***' ,' ***make up***','***have***' or something else that? For me in ***to***'s at the end of construction is necessary but obviously I'm wrong but why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is actually a noun phrase, not a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

To "to" at the end of this sentence is a dangling preposition. If you were pedantic, the sentence would be rewritten as:

> Movies **to** which one (can) have a good cry

The "to" functions as a preposition indicating what you are crying for (or, in this case, to). In the second example you provided, it would be "Songs to which you can dance," i.e, songs that are good for dancing.

The first "to" is for the infinitive of the verb phrase "to have a good cry."

The headline as you present it though is very colloquial and *du jour*, and one could likewise say "Tear-jerking Films" "Sentimental Movies" or "Heartbreaking Titles," etc., etc.

Comment: And if you were such a pedant you would also be wrong. The prohibition against ending a sentence with a preposition has been shown to be false by the vast majority of grammarians—despite the myth's enduring existence and actual claim by almost nobody authoritarian to the contrary. ;)

Comment: The prohibition does not even have to be shown as false. We know it was fake to begin with, as it was specifically invented for the purpose of re-modelling English after Latin by some folks who proclaimed that Latin was awesome and English was rubbish. To which everyone else said WTF and rather than turning English into Latin forgot Latin altogether as a punishment. And so to this day there is simply no such thing as a dangling preposition in English. It's just a preposition, is all.

Comment: Lol look man, I am just using a construct to decipher the idiom for this gentlemen/lady. The validity or elegance of structuring a sentence in a certain manner is another matter altogether...!

Answer (score 0):

> *movies [(for you) to have a good cry to __ ]*

The bracketed "to have a good cry to" is an infinitival relative clause modifying "movies", in which the relativised element is complement of the preposition "to" (represented by the gap notation '__'). It has a modal meaning similar to that expressed in "movies that one can have a good cry to".

Note than a subject can be optionally added, as shown in parentheses.